# Call jquery event handler out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to call a function to add class `hover` to a link outside the scope of the carousel when an image inside has the class `active`. The active class iterates over each `item`, toggling on and off every `3 sec`.

How can i add the class when the item is active?

JS FIDDLE LINK
jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/222

```js
var test = $('.active');

function linkHover() {
  if ($('.item.active').length != 0) {
    $('#link3').addClass('hover');
  }
};
linkHover();
```

```css
.hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div id="slide1" class="item">
    <img src="img1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="slide2" class="item">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="slide3" class="item active">
    <img src="img3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-links">
  <a id="link1">Link</a>
  <a id="link2">Link</a>
  <a id="link3">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Are you looking for a way to automatically move to next item on carousel after 3 secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `owl-carousel`, you should not find a way to call something out of scope, you should look for ways to capture events and then add your code on those events.

You can check [owl carousel - event docs](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html) for events and their signature.

In your case, you need `change` event:

```
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    ...
})
```

Now as per your fiddle, I have added an extra `link` as you have `5` sliding `divs` and `4` links.

You can refer following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/vnpm1y06/223/) for working demo.

I'll try to find a better and more generic way to get current element's index. You can use `$('.link.active').removeClass('hover').next().addClass('hover')`, but this will need more refining.

Let me know if you have  any queries.